# Using "Required" property vs "Is Not Null" validation rule for an Access column

Tags: database, validation, ms-access

I am making a database with queries, forms, reports and User Interfaces - but what i cannot seem to understand is; when in Design view of a table, what would be the difference between pressing Yes on Required or writing "is not null" as a Validation rule.
Would i need to use both or can i use either one?
I have tried looking online but i have not found an answer yet.

Comment: I'm no expert, so there could be some nuances I'm not aware of, but it seems that checking `Required` just implements a `NOT NULL` condition. See this thread: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20857613/What-is-the-difference-between-Allow-Zero-Length-and-Required-in-Table-Design.html

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50085538/ms-access-require-a-field-to-have-something-w-a-validation-rule-do-i-have-to

Answer (score 1):

Both `Required: Yes` and `Validation Rule: Is Not Null` amount to the same thing. You certainly don't need to use both.

`Required: Yes` is preferred because it becomes a fundamental property of the column (field) itself. Tools that look at the column definition (a.k.a. metadata) will immediately know that the column is not nullable. Those same tools may be fooled into thinking a column is nullable if the column is defined as `Required: No` and they don't bother (or are unable) to extract and parse the validation rule for that column.